# Combobox selection issue in gxt

Tags: gxt

Im developing the project by using GXT-2.1.1. I want to display vehicle details for selected vehicleGroup in the grid with checked(checkbox). Im having vehicleGroup combobox it is displaying groupname. How to display the vehicles for selected groupname. Im using two store 1.storeVehicleFrom having all vehicle details and 2.storeTempVehicleFrom having only the under group vehicles. Here under i my sorce code. It will display error msg classcastException.How to solve this issue.

```
ComboBox<VehicleGroupModel> comboGroup = new ComboBox<VehicleGroupModel>();
    ListStore<VehicleGroupModel> storeGroup = new ListStore<VehicleGroupModel>();
    ListStore<VehicleGroupModel> storeVehicleFrom =new ListStore<VehicleGroupModel> ();
    ListStore<VehicleGroupModel> storeTempVehicleFrom = new ListStore<VehicleGroupModel>();// Temp. store

    // combolistener
     SelectionChangedListener<VehicleGroupModel> comboListener =new SelectionChangedListener<VehicleGroupModel>(){
        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent<VehicleGroupModel> se) { 

            VehicleGroupModel vg = se.getSelectedItem();            
            Record record = storeGroup.getRecord(vg);       
            ProcessGroupSelection(record);
        }

    };

     private void ProcessGroupSelection(Record record){
        try{
            int groupId = record.getModel().get("groupId");
            disableFlag = false;

            //if(groupDetailList == null || groupDetailList.size() <= 0) return;commented by meena

            for(int i = 0; i < groupDetailList.size(); i++){ // all the vehicles are unchecked first
                VehicleGroupDetails groupDetail = (VehicleGroupDetails)groupDetailList.get(i);
                Integer vehicleId = new Integer(groupDetail.getVehicleId());                
                Record vehicleRecord = storeVehicleFrom.getRecord(storeVehicleFrom.getAt(0));//getAt(0).get("vehicleId");
                vehicleRecord.set("vehicleId", vehicleId.toString());
                vehicleRecord.set("Add", false);

            }
            storeTempVehicleFrom.removeAll(); // store the checkbox checked for the selected group 
            for(int i = 0; i < groupDetailList.size(); i++){
                VehicleGroupDetails groupDetail = (VehicleGroupDetails)groupDetailList.get(i);
                if(groupId == groupDetail.getGroupId()){
                    Integer vehicleId = new Integer(groupDetail.getVehicleId());                    
                    Record vehicleRecord = storeVehicleFrom.getRecord(storeVehicleFrom.getAt(0));
                    vehicleRecord.set("vehicleId", vehicleId.toString());
                    vehicleRecord.set("Add", true);                 
                    storeTempVehicleFrom.add(vehicleRecord);
                }
                disableFlag = true;
            }


            int[] existsInGroup = new int[storeGroup.getCount()] ;//All the below is for getting the ungrouped vehicles by 
            //storing the vehicle ids present in vehicle Group into array and then comparing with vehicle list and get the remaining ungrouped vehicles. 
            if (storeTempVehicleFrom.getCount() == 0) 
            { 
                disableFlag = false;
                for(int i = 0; i < groupDetailList.size(); i++){
                    VehicleGroupDetails groupDetail = (VehicleGroupDetails)groupDetailList.get(i);
                    for(int j=0;j< AppContext.companyVehicles.length;j++)
                    {
                        Vehicle vehicle =AppContext.companyVehicles[j];
                        //System.out.println("vehicle id in List "+vehicle.getId().getVehicleId()+"total Group id  "+groupDetail.getVehicleId());

                    if(vehicle.getId().getVehicleId() == groupDetail.getVehicleId())
                        {
                         existsInGroup[i] = vehicle.getId().getVehicleId() ;
                         continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
                int flag =0;
                Integer vehicleId = null ;
                for(int i = 0; i < AppContext.companyVehicles.length; i++){

                    //System.out.println("Exists in Group "+existsInGroup.length);
                    for(int k=0;k<existsInGroup.length;k++) 
                        {   
                        //System.out.println(" "+existsInGroup[k]+" "+AppContext.companyVehicles[i].getId().getVehicleId());
                        vehicleId = new Integer(AppContext.companyVehicles[i].getId().getVehicleId());
                        if (vehicleId == existsInGroup[k])
                         {
                            flag =1;
                            break;
                         }
                       }
                    //System.out.println("Flag :"+flag);
                    if(flag !=1){
                        Record vehicleRecord = storeVehicleFrom.getRecord(storeVehicleFrom.getAt(0));                         
                        vehicleRecord.set("Add", true);
                        storeTempVehicleFrom.add(vehicleRecord);

                         }
                     flag =0;
                    }
            }

            storeVehicleFrom.commitChanges();
            storeTempVehicleFrom.commitChanges();
        }
          catch(Exception e){
              ExceptionHandler.performDefaultErrorHandling(e);
          }
      }
```